# weather api, api for iphone, api for php

Tags: api, weather

can any buddy have any code in which with the help of api I can see the weather updates for one week, if any buddy have any tutorial then plz given it to me..

either it is implemented for iphone or for php

thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use google whether in php

see the link
http://komunitasweb.com/2009/09/showing-the-weather-with-php-and-google-weather-api/

to iphone see old question in so :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305127/free-weather-api

Comment: you mean for php ? you can see in the link the example , using xpath

Answer (score 0):

Here's a php example (Note : Needs a valid API-KEY from openweathermap.org)

```
$url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,us&mode=xml&appid=<API-KEY>'
$forecast = file_get_contents($url);
```

You can get forecast by city name, city ID, latitude & longitude etc.